# How would you split this range into subnets of this kind?

Tags: networking, subnet

Suppose there is a network range 150.100.123.0/24 that is to be split into two subnets, one with 2 hosts and another with the remaining 252-2 hosts, how can it be done. The small subnet can be 150.100.123.0/30 right? What will the other be? One can do 150.100.123.128/25, but that only gives you 128-2 hosts right? It also leaves a lot of addresses like 150.100.123.64/26, doesn't it?

Comment: I does indeed. You are exactly right. Which is why network designers generally put all their /30's in a single /24, to avoid these 'cutting losses'

Comment: @mtak But if you use a /24, that means you get only one subnet right?

Comment: In a /24, you can make `.0/30`, `.4/30`, `.8/30`, etc. etc., So 2^(30-24)=64 subnets. They align nicely because they are all the same size.

Comment: @mtak But that would mean that for this case, you would need 64 entries in the routing table right? If you did 150.100.123.128/25 , 150.100.123.64/26 , 150.100.123.32/27, 150.100.123.16/28 , 150.100.123.8/29 , 150.100.123.4/30 , then perhaps you could make do with fewer entries, right. Or is the tradeoff not meaningful?

Comment: Yep, that's true. If you want to use 100% of the /24, and still extract out a /30, then you would end up with 64 entries of smaller and smaller size to cover the entire /24

Comment: You should use /31 subnets for point-to-point links, all modern system should support that.

Answer (score 4):

Subnets can normally only be halved (again and again, so quatered, ...). So a /24 subnet (with 253 usable addresses) can be split into a pair of /25 subnets with 125 usable addresses each.

That said, depending on your usage pattern and OS used, you might get away (in a repeatable, deterministc, maintainable fashion!) with a very asymmetric split. This is due to the fact, that some OSes (e.g. Linux) will always chose from the smaller routing table first.

So you can use both 150.100.123.252/30 and 150.100.123.0/24 if you make sure, that

1. the overlapping addresses are not used in the bigger subnet
2. All OSes involved have the same properties concerning route choice on overlapping subnets.

Just to make it clear: This is **not** a construct inside the IP specification, but it **is** a construct that reliably works under the limits given.

I do suspect, that you might be asking a wrong question here: Those 2 hosts, what does make them special? Isn't a solution on another layer (e.g. NAT) better suited to acgieve what you want?

Comment: Wouldn't a /24 subnet have 254 usable addresses? Are you saying since OS's look for the longest match in the routing table, the 150.100.123.252/30 would be considered a different subnet if the routing entry is present, even though it overlaps with 150.100.123.0/24 ?

Comment: Those 2 hosts are just like every other, like say, a company with a big department of 250 people with a subnet for them, and a separate subnet for just the CEO and CFO, i.e. the two hosts in the question.

Comment: Instead of trying to deploy the /30 route to all devices, I would enable proxy-ARP on the gateway – it's pretty much meant for this.

Comment: (and, is the company really so short on RFC1918 addresses that it needs to use a /30 for the CEO subnet? With two computers that won't even fit the gateway itself, unless you play even more games with out-of-subnet gateway addresses and stuff. I really would not enjoy finding that kind of absolute mess; just find a normal non-overlapping /28 or something.)

Comment: @user2277550 of the range of 256 addresses, the lowest is unusable (the net), the highest is unusable (broadcast) and one must be allocated to the router if you ever want to leave this subnet.

Comment: @user1686 I don't know about proxy ARP. AFAIK, private addresses can't be accessed from outside the network. I mean, what if you want every host to have a static IP, not some behind the NAT thing. If you use /28, then you won't be able to have the 250 dep IPs as a single bunch, right? And you would be wasting IPs on the CEO subnet, right?

Comment: I like your thinking - this helps solve OP's need without slavishly following the rules.  Sure there are things that won't work, but you're point them out.

Comment: @EugenRieck Hi, how is your answer not the perfect solution? What part of the IP spec does it violate? Suppose you have 150.100.123.252/30 and 150.100.123.0/24, both linked to different interfaces, wouldn't it work perfectly? Just set the DHCP to grant from 150.100.123.0-251/24 on interface IN0, and from 150.100.123.252-255/30 on another interface IN1. Whenever there is a packet to say 150.100.123.254, it would match with both the entries for 150.100.123.0/24 and 150.100.123.252/30, but by the longest match principle it would go to interface IN1, right?

Comment: This "longest match principle" is not fully obeyed by all OSes. E.g. Windows Server had the property to reply to a packet, that matches on both NICs on any of them. This is especially true for broadcast packets - in my example above, the broadcast adresses for both NICs would be identical. I don't know, if this has been rectified in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like an X/Y problem because you don't say why you want to split a small range off.  There are other solutions:

- Don't use subnetting.  Instead, assign a handful of IP addresses to a firewalling/routing device (pfsense for example) and then NAT the traffic through to hosts on the far side.
- Acquire more real IPs - if you can afford and need a /24 of real IPv4 addresses, you can probably afford another /30
- Not a complete answer - explore IPv6 as well.  Most providers have more than they know what to do with, so you could request two /64 and allocate one to each environment.  Not everything works with V6 so V4 is needed for a fall-back hence the incompleteness of this as an option.

Finally, do you really need ~250 IPs on the larger side?